# Posts per page not limiting posts in query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a query that spits out posts that aren't featured but for some reason the `posts_per_page` limiter isn't working...

```
<?php $featured_posts = get_posts( [
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'orderby' => 'date', 
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
        'meta_key'   => '_is_ns_featured_post',
        'meta_value' => 'yes',
        'fields'     => 'ids',
            ] );

        query_posts( array( 'post__not_in' => $featured_posts ) );

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
            <div class="news-item-block col-md-4" role="article">
                <a class="news-item-image-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('news-grid-image'); ?>
                </a>
                <span class="news-item-date"><?php the_date( 'M d, Y' ); ?></span>
                <a class="news-item-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Thanks for any insight on this issue.

Comment: "The `posts_per_page` parameter does NOT work without setting the `offset` parameter," ([`get_posts` parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The trick was to target the **while** function e.g.:

```
<?php $i = 1; while (have_posts() && $i < 4) : the_post();?>

<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php the_date( 'M d, Y' ); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php $i++; endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, use `'nopaging' => true` and `'ignore_sticky_posts'=>true`

```
<?php $featured_posts = get_posts( [
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'nopaging' => true, 
    'ignore_sticky_posts'=>true,
    'meta_key'   => '_is_ns_featured_post',
    'meta_value' => 'yes',
    'fields'     => 'ids',
        ] );

    query_posts( array( 'post__not_in' => $featured_posts ) );

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
        <div class="news-item-block col-md-4" role="article">
            <a class="news-item-image-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('news-grid-image'); ?>
            </a>
            <span class="news-item-date"><?php the_date( 'M d, Y' ); ?></span>
            <a class="news-item-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Won't [`nopaging`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters) disable pagination?

Comment: just add `ignore_sticky_posts` and remove `nopaging`

Comment: I'm not sure how `ignore_sticky_posts` relates with pagination. Are you referring to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/70425)? A little explanation might be helpful.

Comment: @Dharmesh and @Pjldesign the value you are passing in `post__not_in` argument is incorrect. It expects post ids preferably in array format and what you are passing is a list of post objects.

Comment: It's not incorrect for my use, which is to retrieve un-featured posts (featured posts are being designated by a plugin, not core WP), and the `meta_compare` method doesn't work to filter out featured posts, so kind of a catch 22...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing here is that you are getting posts object in `$featured_posts` and thus calling `query_posts` is really unnecessary. From your code structure, I am assuming that you are trying to access the main query but with modified parameters. A better approach to accomplish your goal is as follows.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
    'meta_key'   => '_is_ns_featured_post',
    'meta_value' => 'yes',
    'meta_compare' => '!=',
    'fields'     => 'ids',
 );
$featured_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $featured_posts->have_posts() ) : $featured_posts->the_post();?>
    <div class="news-item-block col-md-4" role="article">
        <a class="news-item-image-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('news-grid-image'); ?>
        </a>
        <span class="news-item-date"><?php the_date( 'M d, Y' ); ?></span>
        <a class="news-item-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php 
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

On a side note, I'd advise against using `query_posts` as it directly modifies the main query. But hopefully the above code should help you achieve desired results.